# SetTimeout Overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a piece of my code. The image goes visible after 23 milliseconds properly, but never turns back to hidden like the second line tells it to. If I change it from 17 milliseconds to a value greater than 23 milliseconds, it works. Vice versa, if I change the first line to 16 milliseconds, it works. It would appear that the second line executes and completes before the first line, and so it just stays visible. How can I fix that?

```
setTimeout(function(){img.style.visibility = 'visible';},23);
setTimeout(function(){img.style.visibility = 'hidden';},17);
```

Comment: Your code says: "After 17ms, set the img to hidden. After 23ms set the img to visible." You have to remember both of those statements will start a timer immediately, not after the first timer has finished

Answer (score 5):

Both of those lines execute one right after the other. Then, **later**, the functions you've passed into `setTimeout` are called. They're called according to the delay that you gave. So when you give a shorter delay to the second one, of course it gets called first.

If your goal is to have the img become visible after 23 milliseconds and then invisible again 17 milliseconds **later**, you want to put the second call *inside* the first.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    setTimeout(function(){
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }, 17);
}, 23);
```

That said, remember that human beings are slow, clumsy creatures. :-) To a normal person, that image is basically never going to be visible, 17ms is just too brief an interval.

Comment: I must say, you werent slow *or* clumsy in typing out this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how `setTimout` is working

```
setTimeout(function(){img.style.visibility = 'visible';},23);//execute after 23 ms
setTimeout(function(){img.style.visibility = 'hidden';},17);//execute after 17 ms

.
.
.
17 ms passed -> function(){img.style.visibility = 'hidden';}
.
.
.
23 ms passed -> function(){img.style.visibility = 'visible';}
```

What you probably want is

```
setTimeout(function() {
    img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    setTimeout(function() {
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }, 17);
}, 23);
```

Then, it will look like

```
.
.
.
23 ms passed -> function(){img.style.visibility = 'visible';
                setTimeout(function(){img.style.visibility = 'hidden';},17);}
.
.
.
40 ms passed -> function(){img.style.visibility = 'hidden';}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because 17 is less than 23. The setTimeout code is asynchronous, the second line does not wait for the first to complete. They both run and register the time to execute.

If you want it to be 17 milliseconds later, you would need to do `23 + 17`

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` calls a subprocess with a delay. So effectively, the second line is executed before the first.